# Meaning of a code related to GALLERY_REQUEST

Tags: java, android

I have used the following code  to get a picture from the gallery in an app on clicking a button. It works fine but I just wanted to know the meaning of the codes used. Could someone help me in it?

```
private ImageButton mSelectImage;

public static final int GALLERY_REQUEST =1;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_post);

    mSelectImage = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageSelect);

    mSelectImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            galleryIntent.setType("image/*");
            startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, GALLERY_REQUEST);

        }
    });

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(requestCode == GALLERY_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK){

        Uri imageUri = data.getData();

        mSelectImage.setImageURI(imageUri);

    }
}
```

Comment: I suggest you read about [Android Intents](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html).

Comment: GALLERY_REQUEST is a unique code for your request.

Answer (score 0):

This is the requestCode. It helps you to identify from which Intent you came back. For example if you have two or more intent for camera request and for the Contact request.Whenever the subsequently called finish and need to pass data back to Acivity, now you need to identify in your onActivityResult from which intent call you are returning from and put your handling logic accordingly.

```
 public static final int CAMERA_REQUEST = 101;
    public static final int CONTACT_VIEW = 202;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedState);
        // For CameraRequest you would most likely do
        Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);

        // For ContactReqeuest you would most likely do
        Intent contactIntent = new Intent(ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("content://contacts/people/1"));
        startActivityForResult(contactIntent, CONTACT_VIEW);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
            // code to handle cancelled state
        }
        else if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST) {
            // code to handle data from CAMERA_REQUEST
        }
        else if (requestCode == CONTACT_VIEW) {
            // code to handle data from CONTACT_VIEW
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`GALLERY_REQUEST` is a request code which is used like token, imagine you go into mall with bag, but they can't let you in with the bag so you have to put your bag outside the mall and guy will gives you a token, so when you will come back you give him that token and he will give your bag.

This token is managed just because you are not the only one who came with the bag there may be more, as the rule all person have to put their bag outside mall, but how to identify which bag belongs to which person,they used token.

Just like that request code is used, you may going to several other apps via implicit intent from your `activity` but when you came back, one method called for all intent: `onActivityResult` now you have `request code` to identify that from which activity is user coming from.